# Qt Application add two screen keyboard?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

I'm using Qt4.8.6 develop a Application. Is there any way to add two screen keyboard to the application.

I want to add two vritual keyboard in my Application.One of keyboard is QWERTY keyboard,and another is num keyboard ,it can only input numbers.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement once and we ended up writing our own dialog which served as a keyboard. You can also do the same. I am afraid Qt does not provide just a numeric keyboard by itself which will pop up automatically upon placing a cursor in an input field.